# CreateImagefrombuffer in WinCE

Tags: windows-ce

I am working on a project on Win CE for USB album art. Every time I call createimagefrombuffer, I hit the exception error.

```
private IImage GetImageFromStream(byte[] input)
{
   IImagingFactory imagingFactory = NULL;
   IImage image = null;
   uint size = (uint)input.Length;
   imagingFactory.CreateImageFromBuffer(input, size, BufferDisposalFlag.BufferDisposalFlagGlobalFree, out image);       
   return image;
}
```

I checked the input array and the size; this information are correct. I found this way of implementation from some reference project. I wasn't sure if the declaration of imageFactory is correct.

I saw some websites declared as followed:
    IImagingFactory imagingFactory = ImagingFactory.GetImaging();

I hardly find any info on GetImaging function; pls advise if this GetImaging is needed and what is it for?

Comment: Well your code as posted will obviously fail as you're calling CreateImageFromBuffer on a null instance (you never actually create an IImagingFactory instance).  Where are you doing that?  What is your definition of these (they're not in the CF directly, so you've added code or a 3rd party library to get them).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to do a big assumption that you're using OpenNETCF's framework.

With that assumption this is how I'll use it:

```
using OpenNETCF.Drawing.Imaging;

[...]

ImagingFactory factory = new ImagingFactoryClass();

IImage img;
factory.CreateImageFromFile(@"path to your image", out img);
```

All things considered that I haven't used here the CreateImageFromBuffer method.